# Array with children - display it in the form of parent-child hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tree

I have the data as shown in step#1 and I would like to rearrange it in the form of parent with corresponding children as in step#2 based on the "id":

```
step#1:                                                                                             
[
    {"id": "card:1.usa", "name": "usa"}, {"id": "card:2", "name": "card2"}, {"id": "card:1", "name": "card1"}, {"id": "card:2.washington", "name": "washington"},
    {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios", "name": "illinios"}, {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios.city1", "name": "chicago"}
]

step#2 :   
[
    {"id": "card:1", "name": "card1", "children": [ {"id": "card:1.usa", "name": "usa", "children":[ {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios", "name": "illinios", "children":[ {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios.city1", "name": "chicago"}] }] }    },
    {"id": "card:2", "name": "card2", "children": [ {"id": "card:2.washington", "name": "washington" }] }
]
```

I tried to do the following from my side, but this gets only first level children:

```
var cardData = [
    {"id": "card:1.usa", "name": "usa"}, {"id": "card:2", "name": "card2"}, {"id": "card:1", "name": "card1"}, {"id": "card:2.washington", "name": "washington"},
    {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios", "name": "illinios"}, {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios.city1", "name": "chicago"}
]
var subCardList = [];
$scope.parentCard = [];
for(var i=0; i<cardData.length; i++){
    if( cardData[i].id.indexOf('.') > -1){
        subCardList.push( cardData[i] );
    }
}
for(var i=0; i<cardData.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<subCardList.length; j++){
        var cardObj = {};
        if( cardData[i].id == subCardList[j].id.substr(0, subCardList[j].id.indexOf('.')) ){ //found matching parent card
            cardObj.id = cardData[i].id;
            cardObj.children = subCardList[j];
            $scope.parentCard.push( cardObj );
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this through javascript/jquery?

Comment: You should only apply to your $scope what is necessary in your view.

Comment: @gr3g - removed $scope variables

Comment: @SAM Added a modified solution handling edge cases as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved my solution to make it more comprehensive and also handle the situation where all cards in the hierarchy are not present and in different order.

A sorting is performed on the sub-card array based on id before processing. This ensures order of cards do not break this code.

All top level cards are collected first. Each sub-card is then placed into buckets(Children collection).

I have provided additional data set (cardData1) to highlight boundary conditions.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

```js
var cardData = [{
    "id": "card:1.usa",
    "name": "usa"
}, {
    "id": "card:2",
    "name": "card2"
}, {
    "id": "card:1",
    "name": "card1"
}, {
    "id": "card:2.washington",
    "name": "washington"
}, {
    "id": "card:1.usa.illinios",
    "name": "illinios"
}, {
    "id": "card:1.usa.illinios.city1",
    "name": "chicago"
}]

var cardData1 = [
    {
    "id": "card:1.usa.illinios.city1.municipality1",
    "name": "DumDum"
},{
    "id": "card:1.usa",
    "name": "usa"
}, {
    "id": "card:2",
    "name": "card2"
}, {
    "id": "card:1",
    "name": "card1"
}, {
    "id": "card:2.washington",
    "name": "washington"
},  {
    "id": "card:1.usa.illinios.city1",
    "name": "chicago"
},
               
               
               ]


var subCardList = [];
var subCardMap = {};
var parentCardList = [];
var cardMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < cardData.length; i++) {
    if (cardData[i].id.indexOf('.') > -1) {
        subCardList.push(cardData[i]);
        subCardMap[cardData[i].id] = cardData[i];
    } else {
        //top level cards
        var cardId = cardData[i].id;
        var parentCard = {
            id: cardId,
            name: cardData[i].name,
            children: []
        };
        cardMap[cardId] = parentCard;
        parentCardList.push(parentCard);
    }
}
//Sort the subcard list to ensure missing hierarchial cards do not break implementation
subCardList.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.id.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.id.toLowerCase());
});

//Build buckets(children array) for child cards on the fly 
for (var j = 0; j < subCardList.length; j++) {
    var topCardId = subCardList[j].id.substr(0, subCardList[j].id.indexOf('.'));
    placeInBucket(topCardId, subCardList[j]); //find matching parent card from map
}

function placeInBucket(topCardId, childCard) {
    var topCard = cardMap[topCardId]; //get top card
    var childIds = childCard.id.split(".");
    childIds.splice(0, 1); //Remove the top card id
        
    var childId = "";
    var bucket = topCard.children; //Assign the initial bucket as the topcard children array
    //loop through all the hierarchy and create complete hierarchy
    for (var i = 0; i < childIds.length; i++) {
        var key = topCardId + childId + "." + childIds[i];
        if (!subCardMap[key]) {
            childId += "." + childIds[i];
            continue;
        } //Do not build hierarchy for missing subcards in the id chain
        var child = cardMap[key];
        if (!child) { 
            bucket.push(childCard);
           cardMap[key] = childCard; //Register new child to cardMap
            break;
        }
        if (!child.children) child.children = []; //Add Children array to a leaf card if not existing
        bucket = child.children;
        childId += "." + childIds[i]; //Append the id to drill down the hierarchy
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(parentCardList));
```

Comment: I would like to get the final array result as specified in step#2 in my question. The solution that you 've given doesn't do that :-(

Comment: @SAM I see..I missed the nesting.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Love it more when it is inlined with comments !

Comment: @SAM: You are welcome. One additional boundary check I would add is if  there are no parent cards to start with. It is a simple check once you find a sub-card is an orphan.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you need a [recursive function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwbyhkx4(v=vs.94).aspx), a function that calls itself to nest the children until you find an element that has no children.

So, first, you find all the parents in your list:

```
[
    {"id": "card:2", "name": "card2"}, 
    {"id": "card:1", "name": "card1"}, 
]
```

Then, for each of these objects, you run through the array again, finding descendants. For example, for `card:1`:

```
[
    {"id": "card:1.usa", "name": "usa"},
    {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios", "name": "illinios"},
    {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios.city1", "name": "chicago"}
]
```

This is where we'll need recursivity: you need to repeat the same process again, taking this array as your input. So the "parents" you will find are:

```
[
    {"id": "card:1.usa", "name": "usa"}
]
```

And the children:

```
[
    {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios", "name": "illinios"},
    {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios.city1", "name": "chicago"}
]
```

Since you still have children, you would repeat yet again, until you don't find any more children.

This example might not be as clean as it could be (I wasn't sure how to deal with the ids), but it works:

```
function nestChildren(list, startIndex){
    var parents = [];

    // Search list for "parents" --> objects with only one period-separated section
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        var ids = list[i].id.substring(startIndex).split('.'); // Count only sections from parent id

        if (ids.length == 1){
            parents.push(list[i]);
        } 
    }

    for(var i=0;i<parents.length;i++){
        var parent = parents[i];

        var children = [];

        // Search list for "children" --> objects with ids that start with the parent id
        for(var j=0;j<list.length;j++){
            if (list[j].id.indexOf(parent.id) == 0 && list[j].id != parent.id){
                children.push(list[j]);
            }
        }

        if (children.length){
            // If there's any children, nest those children too
            // Pass the found children as the "list" parameter
            // and the parent's id length as the second (to count periods from that index)
            parent.children = nestChildren(children, parent.id.length + 1);
        }
    }

    return parents;
}
```

[Working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4soo51oe/2/).

Comment: fails if a card in the hierarchy chain is removed. Try removing     {"id": "card:1.usa.illinios", "name": "illinios"} and run your fiddle

Comment: @santon yes, it would fail. I didn't realize cards in the hierarchy could be removed, the question doesn't have any such cases...

Comment: I agree. the question does not have that. but there is nothing which says the hierarchy would be present or about the order.

Comment: @Angela : I was thinking of having a recursive call too but was not sure how to do it. Will surely take tips from your solution.